# How to replace a protected property of an object?

Tags: php, object

I have an object that has a protected property called `$_items`.  It contains an array of more objects.

```
protected $_items => array(object1, object2, object3);
```

My goal is to sort `$_items` based off of a value within the `$_items` objects.

```
protected $_items => array(object3, object2, object1);
```

What is the correct way to detach `$_items`, sort it, then add it back to the original object (or an exact copy of the original).

I already have the sorting portion figured out. The real problem for me is adding `$_items` back to an object that is exactly like the original.

Comment: you mean protected, right? I suggested an edit

Comment: Yes, protected.  Sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to detach it, you can you `uasort` and a custom function instead:

```
uasort($this->_items, 'mySortFunction');

function mySortFunction($a, $b) {
    // logic for comparing goes here
    // $a and $b are items being compared in your array
}
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: It's a protected property.  I get `Fatal error: Cannot access protected property` when I try to run it through the `uasort` function.

Comment: You'll have to do it in your class since it's protected.

Comment: I can't, thus my question.  I'm obtaining this object from another class.  I'd like to somehow clone the object, set this property to public so I can modify it, then use it (like I would the original object).

Comment: We'll you'll need to have some way of fetching the data from the object via a getter or something. You can't modify object behavior in runtime although a great deal should be possible with reflection (but making it overly complicated). Can you change the class in which the protected property is in? Otherwise, make a class that extends that class and add a getter for returning the items.